# How to use taxonomy vocabulary with terms and children using views module

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

I have a problem with Views and Taxonomy and maybe can found the solution here. I have a vocabulary with 15 terms and each term have a few childs. I want to show that with a jump menu using views but the result is awful because I have a list with terms and childs but losing the hierarchical order. Please, check it here (http://cubarecipes.org/restaurants-guide), right column, Cuba Restaurants guide block. 
Thanks in advance, 
Alex

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for the [Simple Hierarchical Select](https://drupal.org/project/shs) module.

From the module's page:

> Simple hierarchical select defines a new form widget for taxonomy
>   fields to select a term by "browsing" through the vocabularies
>   hierarchy. The widget is available in node forms and as Views exposed
>   filter.
>
> This module has been inspired by Hierarchical select but is much
>   simpler (hence the name ;) ).
>
> Unlike Hierarchical select this module provides a simple widget for
>   taxonomy terms only. **As an addition Simple hierachical select works
>   as Views exposed filter.**

The [Hierarchical Select](https://drupal.org/project/hierarchical_select) module is still in development for D7 and the Views integration has not been ported, so SHS is the best choice at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution is the [Taxonomy Menu](https://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_menu) module, this will automatically turn Taxonomy terms into a menu with heirarchy, you can view the trial site for it [here for Drupal 7](http://taxonomymenu.davidstoline.com/).

Another useful thing that may help tidy up your menu is [Taxonomy Menu Trails](https://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_menu_trails), which will allow you to hover and access nested terms.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can follow the below step:

- Add relationship 'Taxonomy term: Parent term' in your views.
- Add 'Taxonomy term: Name' field in views and set 'Relationship' as parent which you have added in your views.
- Click on "settings" of jump menu and it will open "settings" form in popup.
- select parent field from the drop down "Grouping field Nr.1" in popup
  window and save the form.

Kindly see that there would not be link to parent term in jump menu and you can find the duplicate parent term in views, which you need to filter.